# Объединение нескольких списков

Tags: python

Есть вывод данных, в списках:

```
['1', '00:80:f0:49:13:96']
['1', '08:00:23:48:28:05']
['1', '08:00:23:49:08:a1']
['1', 'PcName']
['1', 'bc:c3:42:13:db:2a']
['2', 'PcName']
['3', 'c8:60:00:6d:07:41']
['4', '00:17:c8:59:9e:e9']
['5', '00:17:c8:27:62:34']
['6', 'None']
['7', '08:00:23:3f:c1:0a']
['7', 'PcName']
['9', '00:12:13:02:f6:13']
['9', '02:00:00:88:06:ee']
['10', '00:12:12:03:33:6e']
['12', '50:e5:49:ec:2b:20']
['13', '08:00:23:49:07:dc']
['17', '00:17:c8:22:a6:41']
['17', 'PcName']
```

Первый элемент в некоторых списках повторяется. 
Как его преобразовать к виду, что бы если первый элемент списка уже встречался, то второй элемент добавлялся в уже имеющийся список с таким первым элементом

```
['1', '00:80:f0:49:13:96', '08:00:23:48:28:05', '08:00:23:49:08:a1', 'PcName', 'bc:c3:42:13:db:2a']
['2', 'PcName']
['3', 'c8:60:00:6d:07:41']
['4', '00:17:c8:59:9e:e9']
['5', '00:17:c8:27:62:34']
['7', '08:00:23:3f:c1:0a', 'PcName']
['9', '00:12:13:02:f6:13', '02:00:00:88:06:ee']
['10', '00:12:12:03:33:6e']
['12', '50:e5:49:ec:2b:20']
['13', '08:00:23:49:07:dc']
['17', '00:17:c8:22:a6:41', 'PcName']
```

Comment: соберите в словарь по первому элементу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример через `defaultdict`.

Данные:

```
items = [
    ['1', '00:80:f0:49:13:96'],
    ['1', '08:00:23:48:28:05'],
    ['1', '08:00:23:49:08:a1'],
    ['1', 'PcName'],
    ['1', 'bc:c3:42:13:db:2a'],
    ['2', 'PcName'],
    ['3', 'c8:60:00:6d:07:41'],
    ['4', '00:17:c8:59:9e:e9'],
    ['5', '00:17:c8:27:62:34'],
    ['6', 'None'],
    ['7', '08:00:23:3f:c1:0a'],
    ['7', 'PcName'],
    ['9', '00:12:13:02:f6:13'],
    ['9', '02:00:00:88:06:ee'],
    ['10', '00:12:12:03:33:6e'],
    ['12', '50:e5:49:ec:2b:20'],
    ['13', '08:00:23:49:07:dc'],
    ['17', '00:17:c8:22:a6:41'],
    ['17', 'PcName']
]
```

Код:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)

for key, value in items:
    d[key].append(value)

new_items = []
for k, v in d.items():
    item = [k] + v
    print(item)

    new_items.append(item)
```

Результат:

```
['1', '00:80:f0:49:13:96', '08:00:23:48:28:05', '08:00:23:49:08:a1', 'PcName', 'bc:c3:42:13:db:2a']
['2', 'PcName']
['3', 'c8:60:00:6d:07:41']
['4', '00:17:c8:59:9e:e9']
['5', '00:17:c8:27:62:34']
['6', 'None']
['7', '08:00:23:3f:c1:0a', 'PcName']
['9', '00:12:13:02:f6:13', '02:00:00:88:06:ee']
['10', '00:12:12:03:33:6e']
['12', '50:e5:49:ec:2b:20']
['13', '08:00:23:49:07:dc']
['17', '00:17:c8:22:a6:41', 'PcName']
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте словарь и метод `setdefault`:

```
lol = [
    ['1', '00:80:f0:49:13:96'],
    ['1', '08:00:23:48:28:05'],
    ['1', '08:00:23:49:08:a1'],
    ['1', 'PcName'],
    ['1', 'bc:c3:42:13:db:2a'],
    ['2', 'PcName'],
    ['3', 'c8:60:00:6d:07:41'],
    ['4', '00:17:c8:59:9e:e9'],
    ['5', '00:17:c8:27:62:34'],
    ['6', 'None'],
    ['7', '08:00:23:3f:c1:0a'],
    ['7', 'PcName'],
    ['9', '00:12:13:02:f6:13'],
    ['9', '02:00:00:88:06:ee'],
    ['10', '00:12:12:03:33:6e'],
    ['12', '50:e5:49:ec:2b:20'],
    ['13', '08:00:23:49:07:dc'],
    ['17', '00:17:c8:22:a6:41'],
    ['17', 'PcName']
]

res = {}
for i in lol:
    k, v = i
    if not res.setdefault(k, v)==v:
        res[k] = ', '.join([res[k], v])

print(res)
```

Получим:

```
{'1': '00:80:f0:49:13:96, 08:00:23:48:28:05, 08:00:23:49:08:a1, PcName, bc:c3:42:13:db:2a', '2': 'PcName', '3': 'c8:60:00:6d:07:41', '4': '00:17:c8:59:9e:e9', '5': '00:17:c8:27:62:34', '6': 'None', '7': '08:00:23:3f:c1:0a, PcName', '9': '00:12:13:02:f6:13, 02:00:00:88:06:ee', '10': '00:12:12:03:33:6e', '12': '50:e5:49:ec:2b:20', '13': '08:00:23:49:07:dc', '17': '00:17:c8:22:a6:41, PcName'}
```

Comment: автор хотел получить несколько иначе `['1', '00:80:f0:49:13:96', '08:00:23:48:28:05', '08:00:23:49:08:a1',...`

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import groupby

data = [
    ['1', '00:80:f0:49:13:96'],
    ['1', '08:00:23:48:28:05'],
    ['1', '08:00:23:49:08:a1'],
    ['1', 'PcName'],
    ['1', 'bc:c3:42:13:db:2a'],
    ['2', 'PcName'],
    ['3', 'c8:60:00:6d:07:41'],
    ['4', '00:17:c8:59:9e:e9'],
    ['5', '00:17:c8:27:62:34'],
    ['6', 'None'],
    ['7', '08:00:23:3f:c1:0a'],
    ['7', 'PcName'],
    ['9', '00:12:13:02:f6:13'],
    ['9', '02:00:00:88:06:ee'],
    ['10', '00:12:12:03:33:6e'],
    ['12', '50:e5:49:ec:2b:20'],
    ['13', '08:00:23:49:07:dc'],
    ['17', '00:17:c8:22:a6:41'],
    ['17', 'PcName']
]


for key, groups in groupby(data, lambda items: items[0]):
    print([key] + [group[1] for group in groups])

# либо так, если первые элементы всегда цифры, а их порядок может меняться
for key, groups in groupby(sorted(data, key=lambda items: int(items[0])), lambda items: items[0]):
    print([key] + [group[1] for group in groups])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = {}
# собираем в словарь
for k,v in all :
  s.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
# разбираем в список
res = [[k]+v for k,v  in s.items()]
```